# Is finding "a" given g, g^a, and g^(a^-1) mod p intractable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-logarithms

Obviously, the discrete logarithm problem is thought to be hard.

But what if you are also given $g^\left(a^{-1}\right)$?

Does that give enough information to solve for $a$? Or is that also intractable?

Comment: What do you mean by $a^{-1}$? The exponent would be a fraction, which may not be well defined.

Comment: @B.Mehta:  I would assume $p$ is prime, or at least coprime to $a$.  Then $a$ has an inverse in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$

Comment: What I mean is a is coprime with p - 1 and a^-1 is the modular multplicative inverse in p - 1. That way g^(a^-1) is the 'a'th root of g.

Comment: So if we set $h = g^{a^{-1}}$, then we are given $h$, $h^a$, and $h^{a^2} = (h^a)^a$?

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: Yes. With the additional requirement that a is coprime to p - 1.